# Why does this function return 0

Tags: javascript, logic, ready

I am trying to figure out why this javascript function returns `0` when `this.position.startOffset` value is `0` but not when the value is a number other than `0`.

```
ready: function() {
    return (this.position.startOffset
            && this.position.endOffset
            && this.position.representation.trim().length >= 0
            && this.text.id
            && this.user.id
            && this.concept);
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's evaluating boolean, true or false, 1 or 0... is that the intention?

Comment: In JavaScript, the logical "and" operator (`&&`) returns the first falsy value. 0 is falsy so it will return it.

Comment: What do you expect it to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&&` chain will stop evaluating at the first non-truthy (falsy) value and return it. Since `0` is falsy it is returned when it is encountered. If no falsy value is encountered then the last value is returned:

```js
var a = 55 && [] && 0 && false && true;     // yeild 0 as it is the first falsy value to encounter

console.log("a:", a);

var b = 30 && true && [] && "haha";         // yeild "haha" as it is the last value (no falsy value encountered)

console.log("b:", b);
```

Falsy values are:

1. `null`
2. `undefined`
3. the empty string `''` or `""`
4. the number `0`
5. boolean `false`
6. `NaN`

Comment: Nice answer!

JavaScript is really weird.. Always would want to use typescript, or other constructs that don't rely on boolean operations on non-booleans.

Comment: `NaN` is also falsy.

Comment: @FelixKling facepalm!!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to how javascript handles numbers in boolean expressions.
If the first parameter in a and (&&) statement returns 0, then the right parameters will not be evaluated and 0 will be returned.